# Ace(web editor) REQUIRE vs Node.js REQUIRE

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I'm trying to use Ace (web editor) inside a Node environment (Electron). However it seems that Ace has its own version of `require` function.

Can I **safely** use Ace's `require` as Node's `require` ?

To be more specific: what's the difference between those two `require` ? 
Thank you!

Comment: node.js uses common.js format - http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I'm talking about ace editor's ```require```